# What are some examples of the phrase "being thus made"?

Tags: phrase-usage, example

What is an example of a two or three sentence long excerpt from an old book which uses the phrase "*being thus made*". It does not have to be from a book, any piece of writing will do.

The name of the author and the title of the written work would should be included in your answer.

A writer other than Charles Dickens would be preferable.

Comment: @StuartF No. It is not homework. I was trying to translate a passage of 19th century English text into 21st century American English. I had no idea what the phrase "being thus made" meant. If I can read more examples, I might be able to learn what  "being thus made" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Thus*** is rather formal and is often used in any formal texts, such as philosophical, religious, scientific treatises or in literature. I understand why you are asking this question. It is also possible to say

> ... thus being made

which might sound more natural to some. It has certainly been much more common in the past as you can see from this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=being%20thus%20made%2C%20thus%20being%20made&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3):

[image]

Here are some examples:

> Therefore they saw a Necessity of shifting for themselves; so, to make bad worse, they went to Sea again, tho' not without disposing of their Cargo to good Advantage, and furnishing themselves with Ammunition, Provisions, &c. and ***being thus made** desperate*, they turn'd Pyrates, robbing not the Spaniards only, but their own Countrymen. 
> (*[A General History of the Pyrates](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/A_General_History_of_the_Pyrates/u3V3DQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)*, by Daniel Defoe)

> *An obscure and relative idea of substance* in general ***being thus made***, we come to have the ideas of particular sorts of substances, by collecting such combinations of simple ideas, as are by experience and observation of men's senses taken notice of to exist together, and are therefore supposed to flow from the particular internal constitution, or unknown essence of that substance.
>  (*[An Essay Concerning Human Understanding](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/An_Essay_Concerning_Human_Understanding/tqevBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)*, [John Locke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Locke))

So, once we ***have made** a general idea **in this manner***, we can pass to more particular ones.

And a last one:

> *A division **being thus made***, both parties branded each other as impious. 
>  (*[Church history](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Church_history/k2SWFH1cIbYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22being%20thus%20made%22&pg=PA143&printsec=frontcover)*, [Philip Schaff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Schaff), ‎Henry Wace)

Comment: Your answer is wonderful. You provided me with at least three  historical texts which used the phrase,  "***being thus made***" . However, [John Locke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Locke) died in the year 1704. How could Locke's essay concerning human understanding be published in the year 1996?

Comment: This was the year that particular edition was published. I will take the year away, you are right, it is confusing. The first year it was published is [1689 (1690)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Essay_Concerning_Human_Understanding#:~:text=An%20Essay%20Concerning%20Human%20Understanding%20is%20a%20work%20by%20John,An%20Essay%20Concerning%20Humane%20Understanding.)